# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded data source could be configured

Tags: eclipse

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

ilk pom sonrası xml ile başlayan properties

properties starting with xml after first pom

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.userName = 
spring.datasource.password =
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javacourse.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernateAndJpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hibernateAndJpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
           <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        
      
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please add pom and application.properties/yml to the question.

Comment: The error quite literally tells you what is wrong. There is no `spring.datasource.url` property in your configuration.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found error.Port 8080 required by Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).